# Angular 8 how to apply fa fa icon conditionally but optimised way

Tags: angular

```
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let stat of status">
        {{stat}}
             <span><i *ngIf="stat === 'new'" class="fa fa-car"></i></span>
             <span><i *ngIf="stat === 'active'" class="fa fa-address-card"></i></span>
             <span><i *ngIf="stat === 'resolved'" class="fa fa-adjust"></i></span>
             <span><i *ngIf="stat === 'approved'" class="fa fa-anchor"></i></span>
             <span><i *ngIf="stat === 'closed'" class="fa fa-area-chart"></i></span>

      </li>
    </ul>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FaFAdemo';
  red='red'

  status  :string[]=['new', 'active','resolved','approved','closed']
}
```

I am learning angular and creating demo using angular. 
I am looping and generating `li` dynamically using `ngfor` and based on status I apply fa-icon.
Is there any way to optimize this code?

Comment: I would create a component `status-icon` that exposes a property which accepts status and set its class according to that property.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty solutions to tackle your issue. One may be the following.

Change the string[] to a more complexe datatype.

```
status: statusIcon[] = [{status: 'new', icon: 'fa-car'}...]

interface statusIcon {
   status: string;
   icon: string;
}
```

In your template you can now bind your icon classes.

```
<li *ngFor="let stat of status">
        {{stat.status}}
             <span><i class="fa {{stat.icon}}"></i></span>
...
```